# How to make grails accept a url variable parameter with slash

Tags: grails, groovy

I have this definition in my UrlMappings.groovy

```
"/users/$userId" {
            controller = "adminQuota"
            action = [GET:"getQuotaUser", PUT:"updateUserGroupNo", POST:"invalidAction", DELETE:"invalidAction"]
        }
```

I have read in some forums that uses the notation **
so I changed it to: `"/users/$userId**"`

But it did not solve my problem.

My grails version is 2.3
Is the notation `'**'` supported in grails 2.3?

If it is not supported, what are other ways that grails can accept slash in the URL variable?

Comment: It's not clear from your question, but is the issue that your `userId` has a slash in it?

Comment: yes. the userId contains some slash characters

Comment: Then the issue is going to center around your application server configuration and not your Grails application. Are you using Tomcat? If so, what version? I can provide an answer if you are using Tomcat and you can give me the version.

Comment: here is the version: Apache Tomcat Version 7.0.70